# Unity C# - Instantiate prefab calling a method

Tags: c#, instantiation, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate a prefab using a method in the PlayerController script when a drop event occurs in the TileController script.

If I use in the TileController:

```
public void OnDrop (PointerEventData eventData){
    GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Player", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
}
```

The prefab loads correctly on the scene.

But if I use:

```
public void OnDrop (PointerEventData eventData){
    player.instantiatePlayer ();
}
```

Then an error is returned:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

The PlayerController method I'm using is:

```
public void instantiatePlayer() {       
     GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Player", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
}
```

I think it's something really simple I'm missing but i'm not able to determine what is it.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller class has a member named "player" but it is not set to anything, it is null, that's why you are getting a NullReferenceException. The firs way you did it is correct.

Comment: In the TileController class I have: 

`private PlayerController player; 

void Start () { 
 player = GetComponent<PlayerController> (); 
}`

Comment: Ensure the GameObject on which this script is running has a PlayerController attached. If not then add one. If it does then the null reference is somewhere within your PlayerController.instantiatePlayer method, so attach Visual Studio to Unity using the Visual Studio Tools for Unity extension, put a breakline on that line of code, and step into it to see where your null reference is. The Console window should also show you the call stack of the exception if you click on it (if I recall correctly)

Answer (score 0):

As you comment to Peter's post. 
First check in Start function is your reference "player" equal null or not. GetComponent just trying get component, but if it cannot find it will return null.

If its not null so check, maybe in some code you destroy object under player reference.